# Oracle SQL Loader control file delimiter

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-loader

I want to import a table of customer information to my database. The structure of the data file (plain text) is briefly shown below.

```
"Cust_ID    Cust_Name   Level"
"0001   Eric Cartman    05"
"0002   Kyle Broflovski 02"
```

Each line enclosed by `"` is a record, and the delimiter is a tab. So in my SQL Loader control file, I'll write something like this:

```
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '  '
    (Cust_ID, --?????
     Cust_Name,
     Level TERMINATED BY '"' )
```

I'd like to tell SQL loader to ignore the `"` before each `Cust_ID`. What should I add here? Thank you.

Comment: I suggest loading it into a staging table first, complete with quotes.  Then you can get rid of them with update queries.

Comment: @DanBracuk Thank you for your comment. If this were a real-life case instead of homework, I would definitely do as you said. But since it IS homework and the requirement is just loading it into a staging table, I guess I should find some way to make the staging table look beautiful :(

Comment: Do you know how to get rid of the quotes once the data is in the staging table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [filler field](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e10701/ldr_field_list.htm#i1006668) to ignore the double-quote at the start of the record. This defines a filler field I've nominally called `quote` which is terminated by the first `"`:

```
options (skip=1)
load data
truncate into table t42
fields terminated by '  '
(
    quote filler terminated by '"',
    cust_id,
    cust_name,
    cust_level terminated by '"'
)
```

The value of that `quote` field would be null in this case, but we're ignoring it anyway so that's not important.

With your data file as a table defined as:

```
create table t42(cust_id number, cust_name varchar2(20), cust_level number);
```

... your data is inserted as:

```
select * from t42;

   CUST_ID CUST_NAME            CUST_LEVEL
---------- -------------------- ----------
         1 Eric Cartman                  5
         2 Kyle Broflovski               2
```

I've called the third column `cust_level` because `level` is a reserved word; you can force it to be used but it would cause you pain down the line. Also note I've used `truncate` so this will replace any existing data in your table; if you're adding new data then change that to `append`.